# getGroup of Expandable List Adapter getting executed twice

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I have an expandable list adapter of which the getGroup and getView methods are getting executed twice for the last item in the array. I checked the array size, everything seems to proper. There is no duplicate item.

Only problem is that this overriden method called twice for last row item in the list.

```
 @Override
public Object getGroup(final int groupPosition) {

    return groupList.get(groupPosition);
}


@Override
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       // This is also getting called twice
  }
```

Can anyone please help

Comment: does it interfere with your app? As far as i know, getView is also called many times for the same view. i assume same goes for getGroup.

Comment: It is not interfering, but it comes 2 times